# How can I write a Lambda expression for this loop?

Tags: .net-3.5, lambda

I'm curious how to write this, if it's possible, as a lambda expression.

```
For (int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
{
    MyMethod(MyList[i].Id, MyList[i].Value);
}

public void MyMethod(string id, string value)
{
   // do kung-fu
}
```

I've seen how I can use lambda expressions to call an object's methods, but I can't find one to do it this way.

I realize a loop works just fine. I'm just wondering if it could be done and how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use a lambda expression - but I *would* use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    MyMethod(item.Id, item.Value);
}
```

If you *really* want to use `List<T>.ForEach` you could write:

```
MyList.ForEach(item => MyMethod(item.Id, item.Value));
```

... but I wouldn't.

Comment: I was just curious how it would be done more than anything. Now I gotta look into foreach vs for to refresh my memory. =) Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference/advantage over using a foreach loop vs the lambda version?